# C# - Adding multiple Excel formatted tables

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to perform the Excel 'Format as Table' option from C#.

This is successful for one table, but when I try and add multiple tables:

```
    var range = _worksheet.get_Range("A1:C5");
    _worksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, misValue).Name = "MyTableStyle";
    _worksheet.ListObjects.get_Item("MyTableStyle").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9";

    range = _worksheet.get_Range("A18:C23");
    _worksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, misValue).Name = "MyTableStyle";
    _worksheet.ListObjects.get_Item("MyTableStyle").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9";
```

I would expect this to create one table at the top of the document, and another one of the same size several rows down. Neither tables should be overlapping but I get the COMException:

```
A table cannot overlap another table.
```

This occurs when it tries to add the second table (A18:C23), any ideas why this is happening when those co-ordinates should never produce overlapping tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was caused by me using the name "MyTableStyle" multiple times (and getting the same item each time)

```
_worksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange, range, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, misValue).Name = "MyTableStyle";
    _worksheet.ListObjects.get_Item("MyTableStyle").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9";
```

Using a unique name for each table resolved the issue.